# Angular Material Tooltip is not rendering correctly and nothing I do fixes it

Tags: angular, angular-material

Here's my code for a TOOLTIP using Angular Material

```
          <ng-container matColumnDef="cleRecertDueDate">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>CLE Recert Due Date</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" matTooltipclass="myMatCustomToolTip" matTooltip="{{element.dateRecerticationDue | date:'medium'}}"> {{ element.dateRecerticationDue | date: 'MM/dd/yy' }} </td>
          </ng-container>
```

Here's the custom CSS I made myMatCustomToolTip

```
.myMatCustomToolTip {
  max-width: unset !important;
  white-space: pre-line !important;
}
```

Here's what it currently looks like and nothing I do puts it on top of the date nor widens it.

[image: What my MATTOOLTIP looks like]

What can I do to fix this???

UPDATE 1:

Tried the solution for ViewEncapsulation. Does not work.

It was MISSING but added like so.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-mainsomething',
  templateUrl: './mainsomething.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mainsomething.component.scss'],
  // Need to remove view encapsulation so that the custom tooltip style defined in
  // `attorney.component.css` will not be scoped to this component's view.
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Comment: I have trouble reproducing the issue. I used the example table from [the Angular Material documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) in a new project and just added a `matToolTip` on one of the cells with a longer text (for example "Aug 6, 2022, 6:18:57 PM"). For me, on Angular 14, the tooltip renders as a single line. Could some CSS applied to the table itself be the cause for this weird behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular 15 I solved this problem as follows:

Component HTML file:

```
<div matTooltip="some text" matTooltipClass="myTooltip">...</div>
```

Global CSS file:

```
.myTooltip {
  .mdc-tooltip__surface {
    max-width: 350px;
    padding: 5px;
  }
}
```

No need for `VieuwEncapsulation.None` or `!important`, which could result in layout problems with the rest of your component and are to be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone running into this on Angular material 15... I was finally able to come up with a working solution (with the help of Invest's response above - that delay was a nice little 'hack' to get the dang thing to stay open):

```
.my__tooltip {
  .mdc-tooltip__surface {
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 6px;
  }
}
```

The `mdc`-related style updates appear to be wrapping the contents in another class.

I defined this in my component's stylesheet and included `ViewEncapsulation.None`.

Answer (score 1):

To penetrate the default styles you need to use either `::ng-deep` (deprecated but still handy) in your stylesheet before the css class names or use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in the typescript file.

Read about [::ng-deep](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) from official docs

Read about [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation)  from official docs

Comment: This didn't work. I don't think it was coded correctly at ALL

Comment: You are the Angular Dude :). If ::ng-deep does not work this means you are not accessing the class names in the DOM correctly.

Comment: HA! You're correct. Let me get on that!

Comment: Cool, nice to mark it as acceptable if you think it helped. BTW, There is an experimental tab in chrome to allow you get the right class names based on css properties. It is called CSS Overview.

Answer (score 0):

In the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/examples#tooltip-custom-class) says you need to add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to your component's metadata in order to use the custom style

```js
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Tooltip that can have a custom class applied.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'tooltip-custom-class-example',
  templateUrl: 'tooltip-custom-class-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['tooltip-custom-class-example.css'],
  // Need to remove view encapsulation so that the custom tooltip style defined in
  // `tooltip-custom-class-example.css` will not be scoped to this component's view.
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class TooltipCustomClassExample {}
```

Comment: Tried. See UPDATE 1 - didn't work

Comment: @PeterTheAngularDude Did you try changing the tooltip background color to see if at least the CSS class is working?

Comment: Maybe is just the styles not been set up correctly

Comment: Andres, I'm thinking the same thing.  I'll check and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

The best advice I can give is: Use `matTooltipHideDelay` to avoid that the tooltip disappears. This way you can easily inspect it and check why your style is not applied.

```
matTooltipHideDelay="1000000000"
```

Further notes that worked for me:

- I needed to style the tooltip in the global.scss
- I did not need `ViewEncapsulation.none`
- I needed `!important` or the style was not been applied